# Compare two lists and print what is missing

Tags: google-sheets, filter, compare, difference, google-query-language

I have two tables

1. In list TEST22, which fruits did the buyer buy!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wOZWSPapMTnLGco4POGjsO2nKPdCNIiD_TCsfFjegPs/edit?usp=sharing

In the TETS2 sheet, I want to select a buyer and display which puffs he did not buy

There is a table with all fruits

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u0k3gfDjyWJm3UZlCp3dm1T6QnrM9k3o_9W8nnrvhJo/edit?usp=sharing

How to make column C "What I didn't buy" display a list of fruits that the buyer did not buy ?
It turns out to compare two lists and display what you didn’t buy

TRIED ={QUERY(.....) and not QUERY(...) ) but that doesn't work(

VLOOKUP won't work read data from left to right (

Comment: Not a good question if the links are not accessible to the public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(J2:J; NOT(COUNTIF(B2:B; J2:J)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works, but can it be done in 1 request?

Comment: @KraisAlex what exactly do you mean by "1 request"?

Comment: using only 1 command. to load many tables, and using one query query to get the desired result

Comment: @KraisAlex you can do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSymf.png but that wont look from importrange

Comment: I thought that you can solve it with 1 command at once and import and filter. but it’s also good, thank you so much, health and good luck to you

Comment: @KraisAlex see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL73H.png